# How do I adjust an underline thickness/rule under text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, packaging

I'm creating Supplement Facts panels for food packaging - I'd love to have a style set up for my ingredients. Instead of painstakingly placing all the underlines. Is this possible?

[image: example of ingredient panel]

Comment: I'm not sure everyone here will agree, but in my experience styling like this is *much* easier in InDesign where *Paragraph Styles* can have *Paragraph Rules* or you can make a table instead of tabbed text.

Comment: @Wolff agreed. Unfortunately, the existing label files place the .ai supplement facts artboards inside of InDesign. This is both good & bad - because it is really helpful to see the panels all lined up for continuity purposes - but it's painful to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, personally, do this with InDesign.

But, it *can* be done with Illustrator... a bit cumbersome though. And each line of text needs to be a *separate* object.

- Add a new fill to the type object via the **Appearance Panel** and move it below the `Characters`
- With the new fill highlighted in the Appearance Panel, choose `Effect > Convert to Shape > Rectangle` and enter zeros and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Then choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` and reduce the vertical scale and vertical positioning to adjust the underline....

[image]

[image]

For different weights of lines you merely adjust the Transform options...

[image]

Save various configurations as Graphic Style to "quick apply" the same underline to other objects.

Again, each line of text needs to be an independent object. So, while this would work, it's not ideal.

Setting this up in InDesign is much more straightforward and allows for more control as a table. You can always export an InDesign file as a PDF/EPS and open that with AI if necessary.

Comment: @LisaMartin it would be nice if you marked this answer correct if it solved your problem.